# How to do an elevated 2D Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulations

This is what I call an *elevated Delaunay triangulation*:

[image]

This is also called a *2.5D Delaunay triangulation*.

To do it, I simply perform an ordinary 2D Delaunay triangulation with the (x,y)-coordinates, and then I add the z-coordinate to each point. But I'm wondering whether there is a better way. Would you know that?

Comment: This is the way to do it, you only make the Delaunay triangulation on X and Y and ignore Z. It's why it's called 2.5D and not 3D.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker [Here](https://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=Mesh%5CDelaunay_2.5D_(best_fit_plane)) they project the points on the best fitting plane and they do the 2D triangulation in this plane.